# Caching content read from a large set of files in a ASP.NET core web api

Tags: .net, caching, asp.net-core

I'm developing an asp.net core web api that will need to return data read from a large set of files and I'm worried about anything that may cause the app domain to shutdown meaning that this large set of file would have to be read once more on the first subsequent request.

I was evaluating thus writing a windows service that would do the files reading and act as a "cache service".

I would appreciate comments on this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could store content of your files to [Redis](https://redis.io/) cache.

Comment: I'm not on a public cloud such as azure but yes I could download redis and install it. My question was however more on the idea of having an external process (a custom windows service or a standard cache service such as redis) maybe even do the file reading but certainly do the keeping in memory of the data read from those files and hand it to the web api on-demand.

Comment: Do your files change often?

Comment: Good question. They change once a day.